# Flask url_for DIV ID

Tags: python, flask

I use Flask url_for as part of my Flask app for redirects.

e.g.

```
next_page = url_for('help.index')
```

This would redirect to: `<a href="http://example.com/help">`

Is it possible to pass in a div id to `url_for` to redirect to:

`<a href="http://example.com/help#shipping">`?

Comment: I believe url_for accepts `_anchor` parameter for that. Else you can use good old string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Rather than url for, I do it like this

```
`next_page = "/help#shipping"`
```

this will do the same, But If you want to do it using url_for then

```
`next_page = f"{url_for("help.index")}#shipping"`
```